# Сумма элементов массива с шагом k

Tags: c, массивы, циклы, вывод, суммирование

Дан массив из  чисел 1, 2, . . .,  .
Требуется вывести  чисел  ( = 1, . . ., ), где  — сумма элементов массива с шагом
:
Т.е. 1 равняется сумме всех элементов массива, 2 равняется сумме каждого второго
элемента массива, 3 равняется сумме каждого третьего элемента и т.д.
В первой строке записано целое число  (1 <=  <= 10^5).
Во второй строке через пробел записано  целых чисел  (1 <=  <= 10^4).
**Выведите  строк: в -й строке выведите значение .**
Мой код, в принципе, почти верно построен, но я не могу понять, почему он считает значения между t1 и tk неверно:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int N, k, t, sigma;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    int a[10000];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(k=0; k<N; k++){
            sigma+=a[i+k];
        }
    printf("%d\n", sigma);
    sigma=0;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что исправить, пожалуйста :)
(*Пример: при N=6 и вводе 4 3 5 1 2 9 на выходе должно быть 24 13 14 1 2 9(в столбик)*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**правильное решение получается вот такое:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int N, k, t;
    t=0;
    scanf("%d\n", &N);
    int a[100000];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    for(int i=1; i<=N; i++){
        for(k=i-1; k<N; k+=i){
            t+=a[k];
        }
    printf("%d\n", t);
    t=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А где тут `t` используется?

Comment: я не инициализировала массив t, а сразу выводила. В принципе, не критично, я думаю :)

Comment: В какой строке этого кода происходит вывод `t`?

Comment: printf("%d\n", sigma);//это вывод значения t

Comment: Это вывод `sigma`, а не `t`

Comment: Ну вы же поняли, что я имею в виду :)

Comment: Не очень. Определена переменная `t`, но она нигде не используется. Стоит исправить ответ

Comment: Окей, исправлено

Answer (score 1):

Что-то вы никак с заданиями не справляетесь. Где мои хорошие оценки? :)

Просто читаем и сразу накапливаем суммы в массив `t`. Его инициализировать не надо - он глобальный.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int t[100001];

int main() {
    int N, a;
    scanf("%d", &N);

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a);

        for (int j = 1; j <= N; ++j) {
            if (i % j == 0) t[j] += a;
            }
        }

    for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", t[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: у меня при тестировании ваша программа не прошла по времени. я сделала верное решение и добавила в ответы :)

Comment: А где можно посмотреть?

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/  (написано: Time Limit Exceeded)

Comment: Это просто компилятор. Это не с олимпиады какой? Где проверить? Эту конкретную задачу?

Comment: Вот, никакого time limit: https://ibb.co/yVyPjZp

Comment: Конкретного сайта для проверки задачи не знаю. Просто тестировала разные вводы